# Xamarin Forms - Custom Autocomplete

Tags: xamarin.forms

I tried to make custom Autocomplete as suggested in following question:

[Xamarin.Forms Autocomplete CrossPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417979/xamarin-forms-autocomplete-crossplatform)

it is working properly but there is some issue with UI.

when we type in textbox at that time `listview` visible for selection but the control below the `listview` is moves bottom of the screen. If i use grid for that then `listview` not displaying properly.

`Xaml` code is as bellow:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Orientation="Vertical"
                 Spacing="15">
      <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Entry x:Name="aaa" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Entry>
      <ListView x:Name="Equipment_listView" ItemsSource="{Binding SiteListViewSource}" IsVisible="false" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>      
          <DataTemplate>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Padding="5,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" YAlign="Center" />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
      <Entry x:Name="aa" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"></Entry>
      </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

.cs file code is as bellow:

```
public pg1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person("Abigail", new DateTime(1975, 1, 15), Color.Aqua,"images.png"),
                new Person("Bob", new DateTime(1976, 2, 20), Color.Black,"images.png"),
                new Person("Yvonne", new DateTime(1987, 1, 10), Color.Purple,"images.png"),
                new Person("Zachary", new DateTime(1988, 2, 5), Color.Red,"images.png")
            };
            Equipment_listView.ItemsSource = people;
            aaa.TextChanged += MyAutoComplete_TextChanged;

            Equipment_listView.ItemTapped += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Person item = (Person)e.Item;
                aaa.Text = item.Name;
                Equipment_listView.IsVisible = false;

            };
        }

        void MyAutoComplete_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person("Abigail", new DateTime(1975, 1, 15), Color.Aqua,"images.png"),
                new Person("Bob", new DateTime(1976, 2, 20), Color.Black,"images.png"),
                new Person("Yvonne", new DateTime(1987, 1, 10), Color.Purple,"images.png"),
                new Person("Zachary", new DateTime(1988, 2, 5), Color.Red,"images.png"),

            };
            Equipment_listView.ItemsSource = people.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(aaa.Text.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();
            Equipment_listView.IsVisible = true;
        }
```

please help me how to set i autocomplete properly or suggest me if any other way to implement Autocomplete with `Xamarin forms`

When i use grid, It is shows like this:
[GridImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IoVN.png)

And When i do not use grid, It is shows like this:
[WithoutGridImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCZyp.png)

Comment: Can you post screenshots, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @hankide, Image added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controls can overlap each other when using `Grid`, `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. I'm not sure if I would implement the functionality using the Grid but since you're almost done, here's what you should fix.

Currently, the autocomplete box is sitting in the second row of the grid. It only has a height of 50 so it can't expand more. You should set the `RowSpan` property to 2 or 3 to help the autocomplete box take the space required.

```
<ListView x:Name="Equipment_listView" ItemsSource="{Binding SiteListViewSource}" IsVisible="false" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
```

Comment: Thank you, @hankide. i tried your suggestion but 2nd Entry control visible in background of listview so it is not looks good.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of that too?