# How to implement the address bar we see in Google maps and other apps using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-core, address-bar

Hello I'm new to Xamarin development. I am trying to implement the address bar feature in the application. When user starts typing the address I want to show the suggestions using Googles places API.

I have already got the background service calls to google and getting the suggestions in a LIST and trying to bind the list in the VIEW. But when binding the application is crashing and look of List is also doesn't look as expected.

View:

```
<Entry Placeholder="From Address" x:Name="FromAddressTxtbx" Text="{Binding AddressText}" TextChanged="Handle_TextChanged_1"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextCell Text="{Binding Address}"/>
             </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
```

Can anyone please provide me a suggestion or Direction I want this look like address bar in the UBER app.

Thank in advance

Comment: You could refer to this discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417979/xamarin-forms-autocomplete-crossplatform

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  But it is still no help. I’m really new xamarin or wpf development. So, any code sample will be great full

Comment: Okey, here is a solution maybe your want, I will update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution about using `Entry` and `ListView` to show updated list when text changed in `Entry`.

**Xaml**:

```
<Entry x:Name="MainEntry" TextChanged="MainEntry_TextChanged" Placeholder="Inupt Adress"/>
<ListView x:Name="NameListView" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Navy" FontSize="40"/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**ContentPage**:First setting example data for `ListView`,

```
List<string> adressnames = new List<string>()
        {
            "Alabama", "Florida" , "Kentucky" , "Missouri", "North Carolina" ,"South Dakota" , "Wisconsin"
        };
NameListView.ItemsSource = adressnames;
```

[image]

Now when Text changed , ListView will list updated data:

```
private void MainEntry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var keyword = MainEntry.Text;
    NameListView.ItemsSource = adressnames.Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));
}
```

[image]

**By the way** , you also can use `SearchBar` to achieve it:

```
<SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" TextChanged="MainSearchBar_TextChanged"  Placeholder="Inupt Adress"/>
```

With text Changed method:

```
private void MainSearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var keyword = MainSearchBar.Text;
    NameListView.ItemsSource = adressnames.Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I figured the issue Just now. The is caused by clearing the binding oberservational list

Comment: @LReddy Glad to hear that ! If be helpful, thanks for marking it *.^